# Mocha Test #getImpact "before all" hook: Error: timeout of 2000ms exceeded

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, mocha.js

I want to test a module which runs a jar file and gives me back a result.

The problem is that the jar file is bound to take about 5 minutes to execute and give the result, because of which I get the error

Callgraph_class_traversal #getImpact "before all" hook:
     Error: timeout of 2000ms exceeded

My testing code is

```
describe("Callgraph_class_traversal", function() {

describe("#getImpact", function() {

var gerritData
var revert;
var result;

var resMock = function() {};

var updateDatabaseMock = function(res, _gerritData) {
  gerritData = _gerritData;
  res();
};

before(function(done) {
  callgraph_class_traversal.__set__({
    updateDatabase: updateDatabaseMock,
    up: upMock
  });
  callgraph_class_traversal.getImpact(methodsChanged, done, gerritId);
});

it('should get correct api paths', function() {
  assert.deepEqual(gerritData.apiResult.paths, expectedGerritData.apiResult.paths);
});

it('should get correct api objects', function() {
  assert.deepEqual(gerritData.apiResult.names, expectedGerritData.apiResult.names);
});

it('should get correct cts paths', function() {
  assert.deepEqual(gerritData.ctsResult.paths, expectedGerritData.ctsResult.paths);
});

it('should get correct cts names', function() {
  assert.deepEqual(gerritData.ctsResult.names, expectedGerritData.ctsResult.names);
});     

after(function() {
//      revert();
});

});
});
```

callgraph_class_traversal is the module which I want to test.

I am using rewire and assert to test my code.

Please help me with this

Comment: Try for mocha --timeout 5000.

Comment: If it takes 5 minutes (seriously?!) to load add this to your `beforeAll` block: `this.timeout(  5 * 60 * 1000 + 1000 );` - this will set the timeout to 5 minutes and 1 second.

Comment: This command doesnt run the jar file. So I get a wrong output out of the file

Comment: Sorry I meant `before`, not `beforeAll`.

Comment: Its done. It was not a node js error, i was giving wrong inputs to the jar file.